# javafx - caret position in editable combobox

Tags: javafx, combobox, position, caret

When I press a key in an editable combobox with empty editor text field the caret is always at pos 0 and not at pos 1 as expected. Caret position behaves as expected after pressing another key. Any idea how to position the caret correctly after pressing the first key?

Note: I make the caret visible by following the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239400/javafx-8-missing-caret-in-switch-editable-combobox).

Comment: I would expect the cursor to always be positioned before the position the first `char` would be at. Lacking a char the cursor shouldn't be able to be moved to another position. After typing a `char` the expected pos would be after the first `char`, i.e. at pos 1. What did you expect?

Comment: If you type an "a" then normally the cursor should be placed after that character, right?

Comment: Is this a visual thing? Are the properties wrong? Please describe a squence of inputs that result in the issue (arrow keys and the enter key certainly produce results different to letter keys) and describe the exact issue. Even more important we require a [mcve] to be contained in the question itself. Linking to a thread that allows us to create the code from several code snippets is insufficient. Also there's more than one answer in that thread...

Comment: @fabian: yes it is a visual thing. I'm currently working on a different approach that does not show this effect. I'll let you know if I have a solution and will post an example. Thanx so far.